# unknown size of input

Tags: c, malloc

I was asked to build a C language program that receives an unknown number of positive and negative values, and at the end of the input, I do not know when is, I need to print them in the order they were entered excluding duplicate

For example:

```
Input: 1 8 9 3 3 5 8 -9 1
Output: 1 8 9 3 5 -9
```

What can I do about not knowing when the input is over?
Plus - how I approach this exercise ??
I'd love to get some direction ... I understood that we use `malloc` function

Comment: See [help], point #3: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Comment: use `getline` for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather suggest in-loop [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) with `%d` format specifier (is `int` type sufficient?) and single `int` variable. You need to examine its return value, it should be one unless there is no futher valid input (consider checking by [`feof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/) in you need to be detect for which reason it has stopeed). Then you need to:

1. control your allocation with some e.g. `n` counter and [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and [`realloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) calls. For example allocate space for 1000 `int` elements, but if you array is going to be more than that, then use `realloc()` for some bigger allocation (and so on). Note that OS resources are limited, thus some `malloc()` or `realloc()` could fail
2. take care of possible duplicates. If there is no need to some time-efficient solution, then just scan whole array every time next number is encountered

Answer (score 0):

You will probably receive the `EOF` (end of file) character. You can just use this constant to check against it:

```
//get input

if(input == EOF) {
 // print numbers
}
```

To test it on a UNIX based machine, press Ctrl + D after your have typed all the numbers. This  command will send the EOF character.

Comment: thank you very much!:)
but how do I save an unknown size of int??

Comment: by making a loop that extends your memory whenever necessary. for example:
`while((c = get_input) != EOF) {
  //reallocate new memory
  // save c to memory
}`
this is just a very basic hint, but it shows you which direction you might want to go

Answer (score 0):

you can use realloc to reduce the size of your array.

[realloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm)

Comment: looks great! thanks:)
where do I insert the EOF check?